# Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]

Tags: php, symfony, gmail

не могу письмо отправить с Symfony

config_dev.yml

```html
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
```

parameters.yml

```html
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
    mailer_user: 'user@gmail.com'
    mailer_password: 'password'
```

письмо как я понял формируеться но не отправльеться пишет в профайлере

```html
  Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]
```

Comment: Symfony 3.4 самоучка могу что-то писать не техническими терминами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Как использовать smtp от Gmail](https://www.hostinger.ru/rukovodstva/kak-ispolzovat-smtp-server)

app/config/parameters.yml

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: <твой емейл gmail>
mailer_password: <пароль от ящика>
mailer_auth_mode: null
mailer_port: 587
mailer_encryption: tls
```

app/config/config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
    auth_mode: '%mailer_auth_mode%'
    port:      '%mailer_port%'
    encryption: '%mailer_encryption%'
```

Comment: провайдер порт заблокировал, настройки в порядке